# AngularJS with Rails doesn't recognize $scope

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm working on a project in Rails that also uses AngularJS.
First of all, I have a variable called @resource that contains an end time

```
<input style="display:none" ng-model="remainingTime" ng-init="remainingTime = <%= (resource.available_until.to_f - DateTime.now.to_f).to_i %>">
```

This obtains the remaining time for an X task and is displayed as follows (without display none).

[image: A input with a remaining time]

That value obtained I must access it from the controller.

In the controller I have the following:

```
 function UserEvaluationsNewCtrl ($log, $scope) {
    console.log($scope.remainingTime)
}
```

When I want to access from the controller, the variable show "undefined" :/

Any help is useful. Thank you!!!

Edited:

console.log($scope):
[image]

remainingTime=-39698

-The negative number is correct-

Edited 2:
Complete controller:

```
;(function () {
  'use strict';

  // Define controller
  function UserEvaluationsNewCtrl ($log, $scope) {
    $log.debug('UserEvaluationsNewCtrl: Hi')
    var vm = this

    vm.data = angular.extend({}, rails_data || {})
    vm.evaluationData = vm.data.resource
    vm.evaluationDataStringified = ''

    $scope.$watch(function(){
      return vm.evaluationData
    }, function(newValue, oldValue){
      vm.evaluationDataStringified = angular.toJson(newValue)
      $log.debug('ResourcesNewCtrl: $watch vm.evaluationDataStringified: to JSON output:', vm.evaluationDataStringified)
    }, true)

    console.log($scope)
  }

  // Inject dependencies
  UserEvaluationsNewCtrl.$inject = ['$log', '$scope']

  // Register controller
  angular
    .module('app.controllers.user_evaluations.new', [])
    .controller('UserEvaluationsNewCtrl', UserEvaluationsNewCtrl)
})();
```

Comment: what do you get when you log `$scope` ?

Comment: can you change your `console.log(test)` line to `console.log($scope)` and update the question with the output you get

Comment: @Subash ok! Edited!

Comment: @Subash PD: The negative number is correct

Comment: try `console.log($scope.formCtrl.remainingTime)`

Comment: @Subash i get Undefined too :(

Comment: can you post your whole controller?

Comment: @Subash Ready!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason: The controller is being created before the `remainingTime` variable is added to the $scope object. Don't trust your `console.log` with object.

Solution:

1. Use $watch

   `$scope.$watch('remainingTime', function() {
     alert($scope.remainingTime);
   });`
2. or Use $timeout

   `$timeout(function () {
     alert($scope.remainingTime);
   });`

Comment: It's true, the alert shows the correct time remaining but how can I use the variable in a function? Really $scope.remainingTime contains the time? When passed as an argument of the countdown function the variable does not exist (undefined)

Comment: I made it! I called the function instead of the alert! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening is:

1. Your controller initializes the empty value.
2. You have connected your `div` to the variable, which it can’t have.
3. You have assigned a value to the `<input>` field, which is not connected to
   the `$scope.remainingTime` variable.

Try using the change below which should do the following:

1. At html page init (which completes after the controller init) use `<input ng-init=`... to set the value of `remainingTime`.
2. Attach the `<input>` field to the `remainingTime` scope variable.

   ```
   <input style="display:none" ng-init="remainingTime = <%= (resource.available_until.to_f - DateTime.now.to_f).to_i %>)" />
   <div >
      <input ng-model="remainingTime"> 
   </div>
   ```

You may be able to (should be able to?) use both `ng-init` and `ng-model` together on the real `<input>` field, but I've had uncertain results doing that.

Cheers, Gary.

Comment: Thanks for answering!. I edited the question with your clarifications. The problem is almost the same :( any ideas?